# Select first row for each combination

Tags: mysql

I'm trying select the rows in which `user_from` exists as `user_to` in other row/s which have been created later.

This query gives me the rows.

```
SELECT A
FROM db.table A
LEFT JOIN db.table B
ON  A.user_to = B.user_from
AND A.user_from = B.user_to
AND A.createdAt < B.createdAt
WHERE B.user_to IS NOT NULL AND B.user_from IS NOT NULL;
```

However, I want to get just the first row for each combination of `user_to/user_from`.

E.g. If there are some rows like:

```
user_to = 1, user_from = 2
user_to = 2, user_from = 1
user_to = 2, user_from = 1
user_to = 1, user_from = 2
```

I want to get just the first created one (defined like `createdAt`).

I've tried using `GROUP BY user_from`, but this exclude all other combinations with each `user_from`.

Comment: Please use `DISTINCT` for select the column values

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had earlier misunderstood the requirement.

Assuming no two 'createdAt' values are exactly the same, you could use this:

```
        select a.* from 
        A a
        where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                          FROM A b
                          WHERE (
                              (
                                (a.to_ = b.from_ AND a.from_ = b.to_)
                                OR 
                                (a.to_ = b.to_ AND a.from_ = b.from_ AND a.c <> b.c)
                            )
                        AND 
                        b.c < a.c   
                        )
                     );
```

Comment: Would you need to select min on both A and B in this case?

Comment: I think A should be enough, since the OP just wants one record.

Comment: @Manolo I think it might work if select clause includes A tables's createdAt (either a star, A. star or a list including it ).

Comment: Now it works, but it's selecting two rows, while it should select only the first created one

Answer (score 0):

I think Use `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` query .

```
SELECT DISTINCT A
FROM db.table A
LEFT JOIN db.table B
ON  A.user_to = B.user_from
AND A.user_from = B.user_to
AND A.createdAt < B.createdAt
WHERE B.user_to IS NOT NULL AND B.user_from IS NOT NULL;
```